# Making PLINQ and BlockingCollection work together

Tags: c#, delay, plinq

I have put together a simple application that monitors file creation events, creates some objects from the files content, and does some processing. Here is the sample code:

```cs
class Program
{
    private const string Folder = "C:\\Temp\\InputData";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        foreach (var obj in Input(cts.Token))
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<object> Input(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var fileList = new BlockingCollection<string>();

        var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(Folder);
        watcher.Created += (source, e) =>
        {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            else if (Path.GetFileName(e.FullPath) == "STOP")
            {
                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
                fileList.CompleteAdding();
                File.Delete(e.FullPath);
            }
            else
                fileList.Add(e.FullPath);
        };
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        return from file in
                   fileList.GetConsumingEnumerable(cancellationToken)
               //.AsParallel()
               //.WithCancellation(cancellationToken)
               //.WithDegreeOfParallelism(5)
               let obj = CreateMyObject(file)
               select obj;
    }

    private static object CreateMyObject(string file)
    {
        return file;
    }
}
```

It all works fine, but when I uncomment AsParallel (and the next two lines) it doesn't yield results right away. This delay is probably caused by PLINQ partitioning? However, I expect this query to yield items as soon as they are added to the BlockingCollection. Is this possible to achieve using PLINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what `.WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)` should be designed for.